# Adding stud wall in garage

Tags: drywall

I am in the process of utilising the rear half of my detached garage for a hobby room. We have a pitched roof, so joists are 600mm centres.

I have read a few previous question/answers...I take it that using the 12.5mm fire resistant board for the ceiling and dividing wall is worth it for a number of reasons.

In terms of the dividing wall, what is the better option for timber? 50 x 75 or 50 x 100?

Also, do I need to have a 'step' in the door way to cover regs?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We ask that greetings and signatures not be included in questions and answers. See [our help center](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for more details.

Comment: Reading this wonder what country Paul is from. Does ICC apply. Millimeter could mean Europe.

Comment: You should get some real advice from someone on your side of the pond. I have received 84k is dollars after purchasing a large house that had 5 bedrooms and 3 baths ,,, turns out only the 2 baths and 2 bedrooms on the main floor were legal living spaces , a detached garage, NOT a living space unless WAY More than a wall . So go ahead and build it and try to sell it and end up in court and loose anything you thought you had. I tried to have the seller make adjustments he went to court and lost the house ended up costing me 18k , I raised the main floor 16” and sold it 2 years later for 3x.

Comment: I'm in the UK. A surveyor would surely point out any issues prior to selling, so i would expect any problem to be rectifiable. I'm only putting dividing wall up, so nothing is permanent if it needed changing/removing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hobby room is considered a “living space” and a “habitable room” on this side of the pond and probably on your side of the pond too, because the code is written by the International Code Council (ICC). (See ICC R202 Definitions)

Likewise, Garages are to be separated from single family residences by 1/2” gypsum board on garage side ONLY, provided the garage does not open into a sleeping room. (See 2017 edition ICC Table R302.6.) It DOES NOT matter if it’s a bearing wall or not.

Also the door between the garage and house shall be a solid wood door a minimum of 1 3/8” thick and is not permitted into a sleeping room. (See ICC R302.5.1.1.)

In order for the 1/2” gypsum board to be allowed and effective, it must be nailed into a minimum of 1 1/2” thick x 3 1/2” material at 16” on center. (5/8” thick gypsum board can be nailed at 24” on centers.)

Side note: You are creating a “fire wall” between the garage and living spaces. Usually gypsum board is required on both sides of the wall, but in this case, the “hazard” is located in the garage.

Oh, BTW, it’s not required on the ceiling of the garage unless there is a habitable room above.

AND no step is required at the doorway. In fact, the inside cannot be more than 1 1/2” difference than the outside, unless the door does not swing out over the landing then it can be 8”, or if it’s a handicap accessible route...in which case the maximum difference is 1/2”. (See ICC R311.3.1)

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in the question, the garage is 'detached' from the house, so I take it some of that does not apply?

Comment: Just putting a wall in a detached garage so not a living space! I would question if the height alone would be classified as the doorway is at the roof line.

Comment: @EdBeal The OP said they intend to use the new space as a “hobby room”.

Comment: i See lots of basements with 6’6” ceilings these are not legal living spaces so it doesn’t matter what you call it.

Comment: @EdBeal I don’t understand your basement statement. Are you saying that if a room is not “legal” then you can call it anything you want?

Comment: I am saying it is not a “living space” the same as rooms with less than 6’8” are not a living space no matter what you call them.

Comment: @EdBeal The code doesn’t see it that way. The code sees it as an illegal room. If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck...then it’s a duck.

Comment: Your answer says if it is a living space LMFAO if it is not legal keep on calling it a duck, from what I have read the other side of the pond 2.5 meters is required,,, but keep quacking.

Comment: @EdBeal I don’t understand your comment. What needs to be 2.5 meters? The height? The width? AND the OP is calling it a hobby room. Are you trying to call it something else to meet code? (That’s my point, you can call it anything you want. But when the inspector sees a table and chairs, or sofa, etc. in that space, he’ll call it a living space....it may not be a legal living space, but it’s a living space, which needs a fire wall between it and the garage.)

Comment: The garage has a pitched roof, height to beam, 2.5 metres. I planned to use fireproof board if required for the dividing wall, as the cost difference is negligible. 
I will add boards to the ceiling in the utilised half, just to keep it a little warmer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Paul I thought this was a 2nd question on a detached garage, I looked up U.K. rules and it looked like 2.5 M height was required, , here on this side of the pond what you call the room doesn’t matter it matters if it is connected to a dwelling in the case of a garage, a detached garage both here and there are not living spaces with a dividing wall. Sam is absolutely wrong here but you accepted his answer so good luck.

Comment: @EdBeal Where in the code does it say that a living space must be attached to a dwelling? It doesn’t. In fact, there can be living spaces over detached garages, beside detached garages, etc. The code does not distinguish between attached or not attached structures as living spaces. Paul, Ed is absolutely wrong or he’d cite the Chapter and Section number from the Code. It only matters what the “Use” is...see Chapter 3 in the Residential Code or Chapter 5 of the Structural Code.

Comment: Guess you have NO upvotes try again!

Comment: Thanks both. Not sure how the voting works no favouritism here!
I have been (trying) to understand the rules here in the UK. From what i can gather, detached garage has slightly different rules, what i am planning to do, it is easily reversible.
2.5m head height and another 2.5m to the apex of the roof.
So if i stud a wall halfway into the garage and add some plasterboard to the 2.5m high roof beams to avoid the vaulted ceiling then stop, i can easily remove if required. 
I suppose the ease of removal is key should we sell,unless a buyer says keep it, there is no lasting structural change

Answer (score 1):

Your code may be different but on this side of the pond the thinner lumber would be ok as it is not a load bearing wall. A hobby room also is not a living space so it may not require fire resistant wall board. I would check with the local building code enforcement to make sure I was doing it to code.